# Got "The requested URL was not found on this server." error when I hosted my Symfony4 project in AWS EC2

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, symfony4

I created a project using Symfony 4 and it works fine in my local environment. Then I hosted my project in AWS EC2 and project installed perfectly. Then I access the root, index.php file works fine and it shows symfony 4 welcome page.

But when I try to go to different URL, it gives me below 404 error.

`The requested URL was not found on this server.`
`Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 52.221.55.155 Port 80`

I can't goto any routes which are defined in the `routes.yaml` file. But thease routes work fine in my local environment.

Below is the .conf file I used.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 52.221.55.155
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/oenele-dev-team-server-side/public/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/oenele-dev-team-server-side-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/oenele-dev-team-server-side-access.log combined
    <Directory "/webhost/public/index.php">
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue here. Issue was in my `.conf` file. I change it like below and it works fine now.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 52.221.55.155
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/oenele-dev-team-server-side/public/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/oenele-dev-team-server-side-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/oenele-dev-team-server-side-access.log combined
    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    <Directory /var/www/html/oenele-dev-team-server-side/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```